# Wrong result of call_indirect in WebAssembly

Tags: javascript, c, function-pointers, webassembly

Do not understand how to properly use call_indirect.

Searching the web, I've found that it is not easy to get function pointers work in web assembly. Addresses on functions are stored in Table and basically are i32 identifiers.
Well.. let's code!

Define the semantics in intermediate representation (call-indirect.ll file):

```
define i32 @call_indirect_method(i32 (i32, i32)* %callee, i32 %arg, i32 %arg2) {
%t = call i32 %callee(i32 %arg, i32 %arg2)
ret i32 %t
}
```

Write a program (program.c file):

```cpp
#include <emscripten.h>

int EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE call_indirect_method();

int EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE sum(int a, int b)
{
    return (a + b);
}

int EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE calc(int a, int b)
{
    return call_indirect_method();
}
```

Bunch of js (index.js):

```
const fs = require("fs");
const raw_source = new Uint8Array(fs.readFileSync(`module.wasm`));
const wasm_module = new WebAssembly.Module(raw_source);

var table = new WebAssembly.Table({initial: 1, element: "anyfunc"});
var memory = new WebAssembly.Memory({initial: 1});

const _exp = new WebAssembly.Instance(wasm_module, {
    "env": {
        __memory_base: 0,
        __table_base: 0,
        memoryBase: 0,
        tableBase: 0,
        memory: memory,
        table: table,
        nullFunc_X: () => console.info("nullFunc_X()"),
        jsCall_X: () => console.info("jsCall_X()"),
        abort: err => {
            throw new Error('abort ' + err);
        },
        abortOnCannotGrowMemory: err => {
            throw new Error('abortOnCannotGrowMemory ' + err);
        },
        abortStackOverflow: err => {
            throw new Error('abortStackOverflow ' + err); // Wellcome here if compile with -O0 level.
        }
    }
}).exports;

table.set(0, _exp._sum);

console.log(_exp._calc(1, 2)); // expect to be 3, got 0 instead
```

The way I've built the .wasm:

```sh
emcc -O1 -s WASM=1 -s SIDE_MODULE=1 -s ONLY_MY_CODE=1 -s FILESYSTEM=0 -s TOTAL_MEMORY=65536 -s TOTAL_STACK=1024 -s ENVIRONMENT='web' -s ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH=0 -s NO_EXIT_RUNTIME=1 -s STACK_OVERFLOW_CHECK=0 call-indirect.ll program.c -o module.wasm
```

And finally, call:

```sh
node index.js
```

When everything is "assembled" - I've got 0 in the console. But expecting 3.

Also (a minor thing, but..) if you trying to build the code with no optimisation -O0 it will abort due to stack-overflow error. Dunno why. Any idea? (Yes, I'm already trying to increase memory).

So, maybe someone know what is wrong with my situation?

Comment: Not sure how this is supposed to work, the call to `call_indirect_method` in program.c does not pass any of the arguments expected in call-indirect.il. I'm surprised this even generates valid Wasm and doesn't trap.

Comment: Any idea how to handle call_indirect instruction properly? Or, maybe I misunderstood the concept and there is much simpler way to get function pointers work? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, looks like you just should create an extra table for your functions.

Few notes:

- And looks like this table will be placed in the beginning of the heap memory, but this is not 100% info;
- And also, I don't check the case when you have more then one function pointer type;
- And also, you probably may play with initial size of the table in JS).

```cpp
#include <emscripten.h>

typedef int (*FPTR_TYPE)(int,int);
FPTR_TYPE fMathOp;

int EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE add(int a, int b)
{
    return (a + b);
}

int EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE sub(int a, int b)
{
    return (a - b);
}

FPTR_TYPE my_table[] = {
    add,
    sub
};

int EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE calc(int a, int b)
{
    return fMathOp(a, b);
}
```

So "call-indirect.ll" may be dropped off.